dosubl ods package => syntax errors
I'm writing code to create zipfiles without having to use x commands or exe file.
I have code that works (?) but still get errors in both cases.
rc = dosubl("ods package(newzip) add file='" || trim(left(fname)) || "';'"); 
rc = dosubl('ods package(newzip) add file="' || trim(left(fname)) || '";"');

ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order
I don't see my error, anybody that can help me?
I have replaced the code with other cases such as dequote(resolve(quote(filename)))
But nothing seems to remove the error message.
Strangely, the code works and executes with correct result.
